# Minor (unimportant) defect in the standard?

Tags: c++, string, standards, defects

This question has no practical issues associated with it, it is more a matter of curiosity and wanting to know if I am taking things too literally ;).

So I have been trying to work towards understanding as much of the c++ standard as possible. Today in my delving into the standard I noticed this (ISO/IEC 14882:2003 21.3.4):

```
const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
reference operator[](size_type pos);
Returns: If pos < size(), returns data()[pos].
         Otherwise, if pos == size(), the const version returns charT().
         Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
```

Seems pretty sane to me. But then I thought to myself, wait a sec what's the definition of `data()`?.

```
const charT* data() const;
```

yup, it returns a **`const`** `charT*`.

Clearly the non-const version of `operator[]` cannot be implemented as a simple `return data()[pos]` then since that would be initializing a reference of type `char&` from an expression of type `const char`.

I think that it is obvious that the **intent** is that `data()` be implemented something like `return data_;` and `operator[]` be implemented as `return data_[pos];` or something functionally similar, but that's not what the standard says :-P.

If I recall correctly, implementors have some leeway in that they can implement things how they please as long as it meets the basic requirements given and has the same net effect.

So the question is, am I being **way** too literal, or is this the type of thing that would be considered a defect.

**EDIT:** It is worth noting that the c++0x draft has changed the wording to:

```
Returns: If pos < size(), returns *(begin() + pos).
         Otherwise, if pos == size(), the const version returns charT().
         Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
```

So perhaps I have just stumbled onto something that has already been discussed.

Comment: I was going to suggest looking at the new draft standard, but you're way ahead of me. Little niggles like this are not uncommon.

Comment: Standards are written by people, not gods :)

Comment: @Nikolai: Of course, I was just curious if this is the type of thing that would be considered a defect or if I was being a bit too literal in my interpretations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it was a defect and yes, this was the fix.

> http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#259

Answer (score 1):

I assume that they used `data()` in the definition instead of `data_` becuase they wanted to define in strictly in terms of the public interface.

Comment: sure, but it literally **won't compile** if the non-const version of `operator[]` is implemented as `return data()[pos];`

Comment: @Evan: Unfortunately, they forgot to compile the standard before publishing it.

Comment: @Mike: Stack Overflow detected: you'd need a standard-compliant compiler for that, which requires a standard, which requires a standard-compliant compiler, which ....